# Spark Streaming losing SparkContext

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have some atypical problem. When I try processing received rdd from kafka I got exception (java.lang.NullPointerException) when I try get access to sparkContext. RDDProcessor is serializable

```
def convertArrayToDataFrame(byteArray: Array[Byte], sqlContext: SQLContext) = {
val stringFromByte = b2s(byteArray)
val rdd = sqlContext.sparkContext.parallelize(stringFromByte.split("\n"))
val rows = rdd.map(_.split(";")).map(attributes => Row.fromSeq(attributes.toSeq))
val dateframe = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows,RDDComponents.schema)
dateframe
}
```

The problem starts this:

```
val receiver = KafkaUtils.createStream[String, Array[Byte], StringDecoder, DefaultDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, Map(topic -> 1), StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(ssc.sparkContext)
receiver.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  log.info("Received RDD attempt")
  if (!rdd.isEmpty()) {
      rdd.foreach(a => rddProcessor.processingRDD(a, sqlContext))
  }
```

However when I processing only first rdd, the problem not occur

```
val receiver = KafkaUtils.createStream[String, Array[Byte], StringDecoder, DefaultDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, Map(topic -> 1), StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(ssc.sparkContext)
receiver.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  log.info("Received RDD attempt")
  if (!rdd.isEmpty()) {
     rddProcessor.processingRDD(rdd.first(), sqlContext)
  }
```

I really don't know why it's so problematic. If someone have tips I will be grateful

@EDIT
That I define StreamingContext

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("KafkaConsumer")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Milliseconds(batchDuration))
```

Comment: Can you provide code, where you define your ssc : SparkContext?

Comment: ok, I added this to post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `SparkContext` isn't serializable, and it's available in `SqlContext` via `SparkSession`, where it's marked as `@transient`. So if you can't write `processingRDD` in such a way that it never uses `SparkContext`, you can't use it in a lambda which needs to be serialized, such as `foreach`'s or `map`'s argument (but not `foreachRDD`'s!).

Comment: I understand, but why it's work for one rdd? When object is serializing then all functions will be serialize too?

Comment: `foreachRDD` doesn't send its argument to other nodes, it's run entirely on the driver node (and `rdd.first()` sends the element from some other node to the driver node). `rdd.foreach` does need to send its argument to each node to execute it there.

Comment: How could I skip this problem When I have to process this rdd with sparkContext?     rdd.colect() works, but it's not correctly way

Comment: That depends on what `processingRDD` is supposed to do.

Comment: I created dataframe in foreachRDD scope and it's work, so my each problem was resolved. Thanks Alexey for help.